# iOS 13 Instagram-only photo sharing does not work

Tags: swift, instagram, ios13, xcode11

Up to iOS 12.4 the implementation of photo sharing to Instagram feed (following the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed/)) worked properly, but since iOS 13 it does not work anymore.

With current implementation - `UIDocumentInteractionController`'s UTI is set to `"com.instagram.exclusivegram"` and file extension to `.igo` - there's no Instagram share option visible at all. When I change file extension to `.ig` I can see Instagram share option among suggestions. This way sharing to feed works but that's not the expected Instagram-only solution.

Setting UTI to `"com.instagram.photo"` does not change anything.

The expected behavior is to see view visible below when I hit "share" button, without additional steps. Could that be Instagram's bug or is there some other way of implementing it for iOS 13?

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I am fighting the exact same issue.  I've got the 119.0 version of Instagram installed on devices running iOS 11, 12, and 13, and the problem only occurs on the device running iOS 13. Guess that means it is something that has been broken on iOS 13, and not specific to the Instagram app.

Answer (score 8):

you should add your image to photo library then share the image from it directly to instagram

first of all don’t forget to add NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription and instagram scheme to your info.plist:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) wants to save pictures to your library</string>

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
</array>
```

Works correctrly for **12.4** and **13** iOS

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class TestViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    postImageToInstagram(UIImage(named: "bigImage")!)
}

func postImageToInstagram(_ image: UIImage) {
    // Check if we have instagarm app
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "instagram://app")!) {
        // Requesting authorization to photo library in order to save image there
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
            if status == .authorized {
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(self.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
            } else { print("wrong status \(status)") }
        }
    } else { print("Please install the Instagram application") }
}

@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    // add sorting to take correct element from fetchResult
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 1
    // taking our image local Identifier in photo library to share it
    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
    if let lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject {
        let url = URL(string: "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=\(lastAsset.localIdentifier)")!
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) { UIApplication.shared.open(url) }
        else { print("Please install the Instagram application") }
    }
}
}
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Saved me. Official instagram documentation stating that one should use document interaction apis with "ig" or "igo" extension is misleading ("ig" = all apps are shown, "igo" = instagram app is not shown), this one works flawlessly (tested on ios 13.7)

Comment: checking if instagram is installed using `instagram://app` is not working anymore.